# R point in polygon speed slow

Tags: r, gis

The function `gIntersects()` in `rgeos` package to test if point is located in polygons is pretty slow. Is there a good way to speed up the computation?

Comment: `gIntersects` does not test "if point is located in polygon", rather it is a "Function for testing if the geometries have at least one point in common or no points in common". Check out function `point.in.polygon` (package `sp`)

Comment: @Marcinthebox "at least one point in common" is a general description of "point in polygon"; they are the same in this respect.

Comment: True - I stand corrected.

Comment: @Marcinthebox actually, I have two polygon sets A and B, I want to do a spatial join to find which polygons in set A are associated with polygons in B, is there a quick way to do this? I used gIntersects() but slow..

Comment: Sorry, I don't really have any experience in that - have only used the `point.in.polygon` function, which seems quite fast.

Comment: @Marcinthebox thanks! I found over is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a speed comparison between `sp::point.in.polygon`, `sp::over` and `rgeos::gIntersects()` which were already mentioned in the comments. Note that there is also a `point.in.poly` function in `{spatialEco}` but seems that is just a wrapper of `sp::over`.

I realized that `sp::point.in.polygon` doesn't handle well multi-part polygons (as also pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971447/check-if-point-is-in-spatial-object-which-consists-of-multiple-polygons-holes)) and needs to be provided with raw coordinates (so I presume that for multi-part polygons needs to be used in a loop). Note that, `sp::point.in.polygon` it was faster than all others only in the case of a square polygon, which makes me think is faster only for simpler shapes. All in all, whenever hitting some speed issues, juts try to test for your specific case. For my specific choice of examples, `sp::over` seems a better choice overall, but I would not generalize. Hope my examples are ok, otherwise feel free to correct me.

Since there is no data provided, I used some examples below.

## Testing with world map data

#### Prepare data & functions

```
library(rgeos)
library(sp)
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(raster)
# Get world map data
# (conversion code from "Applied Spatial Data Analysis with R")
worldmap      <- maps::map("world", fill=TRUE, plot=FALSE)
# transform to SpatialPolygons
worldmapPolys <- maptools::map2SpatialPolygons(worldmap,
                                               IDs=sapply(strsplit(worldmap$names, ":"), "[", 1L), 
                                               proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
# Generate random points for entire world
set.seed(2017)
pts <- sp::spsample(worldmapPolys, n=10^5, type="random")

# Define functions to test for speed
gIntersects_tst <- function(my.pts, my.poly){
    rgeos::gIntersects(spgeom1 = my.pts, 
                       spgeom2 = my.poly, 
                       byid    = TRUE)
}

over_tst <- function(my.pts, my.poly){
    sp::over(x = my.pts, y = my.poly)
}

point.in.polygon_tst <- function(my.pts, my.poly){
    # get coordinates from polygon
    XY <- raster::geom(my.poly)
    sp::point.in.polygon(point.x = my.pts@coords[,1],
                         point.y = my.pts@coords[,2],
                         pol.x = XY[,5],
                         pol.y = XY[,6],
                         mode.checked = TRUE)
}
```

#### Testing for single-part polygon

```
# Micro-benchmarking
# The idea is to test which points fall into a selected polygon (country)
res <- microbenchmark(TF1 <- gIntersects_tst(pts, worldmapPolys[183,]),
                      TF2 <- gIntersects_tst(worldmapPolys[183,], pts),
                      idx <- over_tst(pts, worldmapPolys[183,]),
                      codes <- point.in.polygon_tst(pts, worldmapPolys[183,]))
print(res)
## Unit: milliseconds
##                                                      expr       min
##         TF1 <- gIntersects_tst(pts, worldmapPolys[183, ]) 142.61992
##         TF2 <- gIntersects_tst(worldmapPolys[183, ], pts) 125.99551
##                idx <- over_tst(pts, worldmapPolys[183, ])  50.72425
##  codes <- point.in.polygon_tst(pts, worldmapPolys[183, ]) 224.57961
##         lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
##  153.46915 174.42346 162.90885 177.69223 338.2691   100  b 
##  136.13762 158.88218 144.89180 156.91664 352.3276   100  b 
##   55.50899  69.67542  63.80366  78.12026 132.8704   100 a  
##  243.12288 276.71458 257.38068 275.46144 589.9082   100   c

ggplot2::autoplot(res) + ggtitle("single-polygon: 100 evaluations")
```

[image: single-part polygon: 100 evaluations]

Note that for `gIntersects()`, order of arguments seems to matter. Differences are both in speed and structure of results.

```
identical(TF1,TF2)
## [1] FALSE
identical(TF1[,1:length(pts)], TF2[1:length(pts),])
## [1] TRUE
class(TF1); str(TF1)
## [1] "matrix"
##  logi [1, 1:100000] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
##  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
##   ..$ : chr "Romania"
##   ..$ : chr [1:100000] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
class(TF2); str(TF2)
## [1] "matrix"
##  logi [1:100000, 1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
##  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
##   ..$ : chr [1:100000] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
##   ..$ : chr "Romania"
# Subset world points
pts.gI1 <- pts[TF1,]
pts.gI2 <- pts[TF2,]
pts.ovr <- pts[!is.na(idx),]
pts.PiP <- pts[as.logical(codes),]

# All subsets are identical
identical(pts.gI1, pts.gI2)
## [1] TRUE
identical(pts.gI2, pts.ovr)
## [1] TRUE
identical(pts.ovr, pts.PiP)
## [1] TRUE
```

## Simpler shapes - test with two square polygons

```
# Generate two square polygons
grd <- sp::GridTopology(c(1,1), c(1,1), c(2,1))
polys <- sp::as.SpatialPolygons.GridTopology(grd)
# Generate some random points
set.seed(2017)
pts2 <- sp::spsample(polys, n=10^5, type="random")

# Micro-benchmarking
# Test only for those points falling in first square
res <- microbenchmark(TF1 <- gIntersects_tst(pts2, polys[1,]),
                      TF2 <- gIntersects_tst(polys[1,], pts2),
                      idx <- over_tst(pts2, polys[1,]),
                      codes <- point.in.polygon_tst(pts2, polys[1,]))
print(res)
## Unit: milliseconds
##                                             expr       min        lq
##         TF1 <- gIntersects_tst(pts2, polys[1, ]) 151.35336 165.23526
##         TF2 <- gIntersects_tst(polys[1, ], pts2) 123.26241 135.90883
##                idx <- over_tst(pts2, polys[1, ])  54.84891  63.89454
##  codes <- point.in.polygon_tst(pts2, polys[1, ])   9.39330  10.66513
##       mean    median        uq       max neval  cld
##  189.67848 177.62808 190.89566 365.92728   100    d
##  157.47151 148.50073 160.37567 314.02700   100   c 
##   76.42608  70.66998  79.81225 240.55570   100  b  
##   14.09199  11.37738  16.88741  46.19245   100 a

ggplot2::autoplot(res) + ggtitle("square polygon: 100 evaluations")
```

[image: test with square polygons]

```
pts2.gI1 <- pts2[TF1,]
pts2.gI2 <- pts2[TF2,]
pts2.ovr <- pts2[!is.na(idx),]
pts2.PiP <- pts2[as.logical(codes),]
# All subsets are identical
identical(pts2.gI1, pts2.gI2)
## [1] TRUE
identical(pts2.gI2, pts2.ovr)
## [1] TRUE
identical(pts2.ovr, pts2.PiP)
## [1] TRUE
```

Session Info

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] raster_2.5-8           mapview_1.2.0          leaflet_1.1.0          maptools_0.9-2         maps_3.1.1            
[6] ggplot2_2.2.1          microbenchmark_1.4-2.1 sp_1.2-4               rgeos_0.3-23
```