# Subset Spatial Points to Extract those inside of a Polygon (Countries Borders)

Tags: r, raster, geo, r-sp, spatial-data-frame

I have a data.frame with lat long coordinates:

```
df<-data.frame(
     lat=c(40, 30, 40.864),
     lon=c(0, 20, 1.274)
    )
```

And the border of a country (Spain),

```
library(raster)
border <- getData("GADM",country="Spain",level=0)
```

I would like to select for `df` only the points *inside* the `border`.

How can I do this?

***Note:*** in my reproducible example, `df`, the first entry point is inside, the second is clearly outside and the third is outside but close to the coast.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971447/check-if-point-is-in-spatial-object-which-consists-of-multiple-polygons-holes

Comment: In fact the question @Masoud links is very similar to my question. However, it does not work. 

    sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i){gContains(spa.mask, SpatialPoints(df[i,], proj4string = CRS(proj4string(spa.mask))))})

This returns `FALSE` for the three points. I do not understand why. Maybe because my border contains several polygons (islands and peninsula)?

Comment: As I say in the question, one of them is inside the border. I do not underestand what you mean by "map". I made a plot and checked that the point falls inside the polygon and the other two outside the polygon...

Comment: Check my answer. My guess is that you were implementing part of that solution in a wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I believe the post that I referred to answers this question, I think some clarification is needed; hence, posting an answer.

To find the intersection of two geographic feature, we need to have the same projection. [sp](/questions/tagged/sp) library helps us to do so. Make sure to put longitude and latitude in the right place:

`sp::SpatialPoints(c(my_point$long,my_point$lat),proj4string=CRS(proj4string(my_raster)))`

Using [rgeos](/questions/tagged/rgeos) library we can check if there is an intersection between two spatial dataset/feature:

`rgeos::gContains(my_raster,my_projected_point)`

So, here is how it works for the OP's example:

```
library(sp)        #for projection
library(raster)    #for getting the border data
library(rgeos)     #for finding intersection
library(tidyverse) #for illustration only

#data
border <- getData("GADM",country="Spain",level=0)
df <- data.frame(
 lat=c(40, 30, 40.864),
 lon=c(0, 20, 1.274)
                )

#this is the part that actually check if a point is inside the border
#adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971447
sapply(1:3,function(i)
  list(id=i,
       intersect= gContains(border,SpatialPoints(df[i,2:1],proj4string=CRS(proj4string(border))))))

#           [,1] [,2]  [,3] 
# id        1    2     3    
# intersect TRUE FALSE FALSE

#a map for better understanding
ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data=border, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), 
                       fill=NA, color="grey50", size=0.25) +
  geom_point(data=df,aes(x=lon,y=lat), color="red", size=1)
```

[image]