# Combining spatial data

Tags: r, gis, r-sp, rworldmap

I am trying to combine the two datasets found here:

One is a world map taken from `map_data('world')` and the other is lat/lon of black carbon emissions in 1960. I would like to merge the two so that I can summarize emissions based on country. So far I have been unsuccessful.

My impression is the `sp` package is the right tool here. Specifically, the `over()` function with the world map being a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` and the emissions data being a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` but I can't seem to get things to work.

Any help is much appreciated. I would also be happy to hear of any suggestions for solid references on GIS and R.

EDIT: I ended up using `data(countriesCoarse)` from the `rworldmap` package instead of `map_data('world')`. This had the advantage of already being a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`. `over()` now appears to be working as desired. I took down the broken link for the data.

Comment: I could not see what you have in your Rdata file. But, are you thinking about something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748852/choropleth-map-in-ggplot-with-polygons-that-have-holes)? This is just an example. But, this may help you a bit.

Comment: Your file does not import properly for me either. Can you save it again, or better just provide a link to the second file in its original format (cvs or whatever).

Comment: Sorry for the data fail.  Thanks for taking a look.