# R - ggplot shapefile small features overlaped by bigger ones

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial, shapefile

when I use ggplot2::ggplot() to create a map using a shapefile I have the problem that small features overlaped by bigger ones. Please note [image of the Problem: ggplot overlays the small county by the bigger one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njvx9.png).

Please use this [shapefile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tpgnctfc7kgrlrw/Germany_Bremen_LowerSax_NUTS1.Rdata?dl=0) as input data.

```
load("~/Germany_Bremen_LowerSax_NUTS1.Rdata") # Please use input data mentioned above
library(ggplot2)

plot(shp.nuts.test) # normal plot with visible borders.

shp.f <- fortify(shp.nuts.test)

Map <-   ggplot(shp.f, aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = id))+
  geom_polygon()
Map
```

Is there any possibility to change the plot order of the shapefile within ggplot?

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options:

1. Reorder factors so that the lower levels plot on top of the higher ones.
2. Add another layer of the hidden group over the plot (shown below)

> ```
> library(dplyr)
>
> ggplot(shp.f, aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = id))+
> geom_polygon()+
> geom_polygon(aes(long,lat), data=filter(shp.f, group=='4.1'))
> ```

[image]

I personally prefer option 2, because it is a huge pain reordering factors and can easily result in unintended consequences.  In addition, you could handle more layers on top.  Note that the filter function requires the `dplyr` library ([more on dplyr use](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr)).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! This is a simple and straight forward solution for this example. But I am looking for a **more general solution** because I want to plot more complex polygon shapefiles (e.g. NUTS3-level). I need to ensure that ggplot plot the polygon features the way that smaller features are not hidden by bigger ones. In QGIS that is no problem without doing any corrections but I unfortunately this seems not to be the case in R/ggplot.

Comment: Yes, I can see that you'd want a general fix rather than a kludge.  You could make the fill transparent, such that you can always see each, but you'd lose control of the colors to an extent.  It is possible that ggplot is not the best tool to plot this type of map.  Have you looked at the [CRAN task views](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html) for other options?

Comment: I have found a good solution that works for me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32186989/2725410).