# Plot ggplot polygons with holes with geom_polygon

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, r-sp

There are [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748852/choropleth-map-in-ggplot-with-polygons-that-have-holes) out there about the fact that `ggplot2` can't plot polygon shapes that have **holes**.

That is because, if the order of points is not OK, the end graph looks bad, usually with clipping/trimming lines inside the donut shape.

I have read a lot about how order matters, but I am not able to step forward.
I have a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` with 26 features (comes from `raster::rasterToPolygons(dissolve=T)`) and I want to plot it with `ggplot`.

Here's what happens -

```
r3.pol <- rasterToPolygons(r3, dissolve=T)
r3.df <- fortify(r3.pol)
names(r3.df) <- c('x','y','order','hole','piece','ID','group')
p <- ggplot(r3.df)
p <- p + geom_polygon(mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,group=ID), fill='red')
p <- p + coord_equal()
```

I see this output:

[image]

While it should be like so, with `plot(r3.pol)`:

[image]

How can I make this work?
I tried for hours but I am not able to reorder `r3.df`.
Also, can the information in `r3.df$hole` be helpful? It is returned by the function `fortify` for points that are holes (I think).

<strike>*Side question: how can I give you my r3.pol SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, so that you can try yourself? I remember seeing long, reproducible "dumps" of objects here, but I don't know how to do it.*</strike>

I `save`d the polygons data frame [**here**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8KkBDlTQxNsMm0tQktHUHhqZnc/view?usp=sharing). Was not able to save it using `dput`, sorry. You can fetch it using `load`.

Comment: You don't need to provide your whole data frame. Just a smaller sample with a few separate polygons. Paste into your question the output of `dput(dataSample)`.

Comment: @eipi10 That was it! But I'm having troubles using it. It doesn't seem to work on a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. And if I use it on r3.df, even with subsampling, it's still a huge dump. I think I'll use some log provider out there.

Comment: I'd say ditch ggplot2 for maps and use package:tmap - handles holes, no more needing to `fortify` everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My temporary solution is: @#$% polygons, and use the `raster` package.

Namely:

```
r <- raster(x=extent(r3.pol), crs=crs(r3.pol)) # empty raster from r3.pol
res(r) <- 250 # set a decent resolution (depends on your extent)
r <- setValues(r, 1) # fill r with ones
r <- mask(r, r3.pol) # clip r with the shape polygons
```

And now plot it as you would do with any `raster` with `ggplot`. The `rasterVis` package might come helpful here, but I'm not using it, so:

```
rdf <- data.frame(rasterToPoints(r))
p <- ggplot(rdf) + geom_raster(mapping=aes(x=x, y=y), fill='red')
p <- p + coord_equal()
```

And here it goes.

[image]

Alternatively, you can create the raster with `rasterize`, so the raster will hold the polygons values (in my case, just an integer):

```
r <- raster(x=extent(r3.pol), crs=crs(r3.pol))
res(r) <- 250
r <- rasterize(r3.pol, r)

rdf <- data.frame(rasterToPoints(r))
p <- ggplot(rdf) + geom_raster(mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, fill=factor(layer)))
p <- p + coord_equal()
```

[image]

If someone comes up with a decent solution for `geom_polygon`, probably involving re-ordering of the polygons data frame, I'll be glad to consider it.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to install the package "ggpolypath" and use geom_polypath instead of geom_polygon. Works for me.

Comment: Note that while `ggpolypath` still appears to be maintained, with R >= 3.6 the package is no longer needed. From https://mdsumner.github.io/ggpolypath/ it recommends: *"ggpolypath predates full support for polygonal path geoemtry in ggplot2, we advise use of the ggplot2 package directly rather than this package, please see https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/ggplot2-3-2-0/."*