# Avoiding hoizontal lines and crazy shapes when plotting maps in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, gis, polygon

I want a plot of an area, such as Latin America, using the world shape file from IPUMSI...

https://international.ipums.org/international/resources/gis/IPUMSI_world.zip

... I will add some more IPUMS districts later so I really want to use this as my template layer.

I having difficulty with the plot when I add limits through `coord_map` in ggplot2.

The initial spatial file looks alright

```
library("ggplot2")
library("raster")

sd0 <- readShapePoly("./IPUMSI_world.shp")
df0 <- fortify(sd0)

ggplot(data = df0, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(fill = "black", colour = "black")
```

[image]

When I want to focus on Latin America I get some unwanted horizontal lines:

```
ggplot(data = df0, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(fill = "black", colour = "black") +
  coord_map(xlim = c(-125, -30), ylim = c(-60, 35))
```

[image]

I tried to fix this using the `clipPolys` function, following the guidance [here](http://cameron.bracken.bz/finally-an-easy-way-to-fix-the-horizontal-lines-in-ggplot2-maps)

```
library("PBSmapping")
df1 <- df0
names(df1)[c(1,2,6,3)] <- c("X","Y","PID","POS")
df1$PID <- as.numeric(df1$PID)
df2 <- clipPolys(polys = df1, xlim = c(-125, -30), ylim = c(-60, 35), keepExtra = TRUE)
names(df2)[names(df2)=="X"] <- "long" 
names(df2)[names(df2)=="Y"] <- "lat"
names(df2)[names(df2)=="PID"] <- "id"

ggplot(data = df2, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(fill = "black", colour = "black")
```

[image]

Not really super happy with this plot either. I thought it was a problem with holes, as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21748852/513463), but the suggested solution produces the same plots as above:

```
gghole <- function(fort){
  poly <- fort[fort$id %in% fort[fort$hole,]$id,]
  hole <- fort[!fort$id %in% fort[fort$hole,]$id,]
  out <- list(poly,hole)
  names(out) <- c('poly','hole')
  return(out)
} 

ggplot(df2, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
  geom_polygon(data = gghole(df2)[[1]], fill = "black", colour = "black") +
  geom_polygon(data = gghole(df2)[[2]], fill = "black", colour = "black")

ggplot(df0, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
  geom_polygon(data = gghole(df0)[[1]], fill = "black", colour = "black") +
  geom_polygon(data = gghole(df0)[[2]], fill = "black", colour = "black") +
  coord_map(xlim = c(-125, -30), ylim = c(-60, 35))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]The other solution is to restrict the view, rather than remove point from the render:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maptools)
library(mapproj)

# Maptools dataset
data(wrld_simpl)
world <- fortify(wrld_simpl)

# Same plot, but restrict the view instead of removing points
# allowing the complete render to happen
ggplot(world, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(fill = "black", colour = "black") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-125, -30), ylim = c(-60, 35))
```

Comment: I think this will be slower than setting limits in scale_continuous, because the whole data will be calculated then clipped. scale_continuous will only render the data you want plotted.

Comment: Slower, but you won't get bits of countries missing.

Comment: Fair point. So, I guess it depends on the end use which would be preferred. The 'missing' bits of countries are the parts you tell it to omit by setting the limits, which may or may not be what the user wants.

Answer (score 4):

You should delete the data outside the plot region. So, use `scale_x/y_continuous` to set the limits instead of `coord_map`

```
ggplot(data = df0, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-125, -30)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-60, 35)) +
  geom_polygon(fill = "black", colour = "black")
```

[image]