# Ggplot polygon map with enclave that gets coloured wrongly

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, polygon, enclave

I am making maps of the Region Hovedstaden in Denmark, which is the part that contains Copenhagen (København in the legend). The area is divided into "kommune"s that I want coloured differently. Alas, inside the Copenhagen kommune is an enclave - a different kommune - called Frederiksberg - which should thus be coloured differently from Copenhagen. But as seen from the map attached, it doesn't although the legend show the two kommunes with different colours. I presume this is because Frederiksberg is drawn/coloured first, then Copenhagen kommune is drawn above it. Surprisingly, though, the polygon outline is shown.

Plot code (which filters out some outlier islands):

```
    ggplot(data = combmapscaled %>% filter(!(kommuner == "Christiansø" | (kommuner == "Halsnæs" & lat > 6220000)))) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long,
                   y = lat, 
                   fill = factor(kommuner), 
                   group = group),
               color = "white") +
  coord_fixed(1)
```

Sample of "combmapscaled":

```
> head(combmapscaled)
      long     lat order  hole piece id group  kommuner V3 komcolours
1 726922.8 6179025     1 FALSE     1 30  30.1 København  1          1
2 726925.3 6179026     2 FALSE     1 30  30.1 København  1          1
3 726976.7 6179042     3 FALSE     1 30  30.1 København  1          1
4 726984.5 6179042     4 FALSE     1 30  30.1 København  1          1
5 726986.8 6179052     5 FALSE     1 30  30.1 København  1          1
6 727001.1 6179116     6 FALSE     1 30  30.1 København  1          1
```

Map:

Kommunes in the region, not quite coloured by kommune
[image: Kommunes in the region, not quite coloured by kommune]

So, a workaround, please... Draw Frederiksberg (again) over it all?

TIA,
Jens

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748852/choropleth-map-in-ggplot-with-polygons-that-have-holes/32186989

Comment: Thanks! The simplest in my case is to (re)draw the enclave.